# Moving a image and adding it to a picturebox

Tags: c#, image, winforms

Im working on a game launcher in WinForms where you can add games by yourself but i've run into a problem. i want to be able to add an image to the game you add
(this is what i want it to look like when done)
[image]

Adding the text and pressing the picturebox to launch the game works just as i want it to but i have no clue on how i would add the image.

The form which i add a game from looks like this:
[image]

Now what i want the "Add Image" button to do is open a OpenFileDialog where you can select your image and then it will be saved in the same folder as the rest of the files and then loaded in the first form.

> string dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/App Launcher/Games";

I have looked around for a bit but haven't found anything for C#

Any help or links to similar post would be helpful!

Comment: Do you want to know how to move files, manage the storage of the various images, or how to apply an image to the PictureBox?

Comment: You can't figure out how to use `OpenFileDialog` or how to copy the file to your directory?

Comment: i don't know how to copy the file to my direcotory and then add it to the picturebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `button` click event open your file dialog:

```
if( openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ) {
    string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName; //take whole path

    File.Copy( filePath, @"Directory you want to be saved\" + Path.GetFileName( filePath ) );

    //in case file is not valid image
    try {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile( filePath ); //set image to picbox
    }
    catch( Exception ex ) {
        MessageBox.Show( ex.ToString() );
    }
}
```

You should make file dialog to open image extensions like `.bmp, .png, .jpg, ...`